# How can I insert pandas dataframe to database without data duplication?

Tags: python, pandas, pymysql

I used .to_sql function to insert data. But it can't check duplicated insert data. (It only can check the duplicated tables)

source code) when I run twice of the source code below.

```
userData.to_sql(con=engine, name='test_quest_complete', schema='test', if_exists='append')
```

the results) Same data was inserted in the table.

```
0   2016-11-14 00:00:10 AAAA
1   2016-11-14 00:00:20 BBBB
0   2016-11-14 00:00:10 AAAA
1   2016-11-14 00:00:20 BBBB
```

How can I insert pandas dataframe to database without data duplication?

(Also, I tried to use load data local infile, but I can't use it by reason of security issues.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have administration rights on your database, I would suggest you to put some constraints on the table itself. Then the python insertion will raise an exception (and you can intercept it).
Else you can also try to retrieve the data first from the table and merge it inside pandas. Then do a group by on all the columns and get the non-existent data as a new dataframe and insert it.

Comment: I think it's a right direction - OP would want to create a `Primary Key` or a `Unique Key` constraint. But they don't necessarily need administration rights - `ALTER TABLE` privilege for the schema/user owning this table should be enough. IMO reading the whole table into pandas DF and checking for duplicates on the pandas side would "ruin" the idea of storing this data in a SQL DB... just my 0.02$

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


##Data of Excel File - ExcelData(Sheet1)
##id    name
##1 11
##2 22
##3 33
##4 44
##5 55


##CREATE TABLE [test].[test_quest_complete](
##  [id] [int] NULL,
##  [name] [int] NULL
##) 


TblName="test_quest_complete"
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect("dsn=mydsn;Trusted_Connection=Yes")
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://mydsn")

file_name="C:\Users\poonamr\Desktop\ExcelData.xlsx"
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)
userData = xl.parse("Sheet1")
print(userData)

sql="Select * From test." + TblName
tblData=pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)
print(tblData)

Finalresult=pd.concat([userData, tblData]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(Finalresult)

Finalresult.to_sql(TblName, engine, if_exists='append',schema='test', index=False)
```

Comment: using .to_sql function can't be avoid duplicate values in the same table. when you run the your code again, the same data will be insterted or occured error message 'duplicate entry~~'

Comment: First you need to take data from table into dataframe, then compare userdata against table and drop duplicates, and write final data into table with to_sql

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. When I apply your suggestion to the small data, it will be fine. But I apply the suggestion in the big data. Can I get effective performance in comparing the all data in database?

Comment: yup, because somewhere you need this comparison to remove duplicate, either at sql side/python side. Its better to use python resources, rather than database.